# Getting ExecTask output into an ItemCollection

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build, stylecop

I am writing a simple MSBuild script where i would like to perform the following:

- Run a command line tool using the Exec Task.
- Get the output from the tool into some item collection.
- Use this collection as input to another task.

The context of this, is that we have several command line static analysis and other analysis tools (think of StyleCop).

I would like to run a *git diff* command and get ONLY the files from latest commit and feed these into StyleCop or whatever other analysis tools.

I could not find any reference on how to do this with the Exec task.

EDIT: I am trying to use the ReadLinesFromFile task:

> ```
> <Exec 
>   Command="git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD > C:\output.txt"
>   WorkingDirectory="D:\Code" />
>
> <ReadLinesFromFile
>   File="C:\output.txt">
>   <Output
>     TaskParameter="Lines"
>     ItemName="ItemsFromFile" />
> </ReadLinesFromFile>
>
> <StyleCopTask
>   ProjectFullPath="$(MSBuildProjectFile)"
>   SourceFiles="@(ItemsFromFile)"
>   ForceFullAnalysis="true"
>   TreatErrorsAsWarnings="true"
>   OutputFile="StyleCopReport.xml"
>   CacheResults="true" />
> ```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Am i using the ItemsFromFile collection correctly ?

Comment: The `ReadLinesFromFile` and `StyleCopTask` look fine. What does `output.txt` look like? If it contains a single full source code file path per line this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect the output of the Exec task to a file, you can use the ReadLinesFromFile task: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164299.aspx

Comment: I can do it, thought there's an easier and cleaner way of doing this.